# Issue With Using Ansible and WinRM

Tags: ansible, winrm

I am running into issues testing out ansible with WinRM.

I have setup an HTTP listener on a Windows 10 test VM. I also created a simple playbook that is supposed to create a folder on the user's desktop.

When I run the playbook I receive the error

```
fatal: [192.168.10.42]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The installed version of WinRM does not support transport(s) ['http']"
```

The following is my the playbook that I am trying to run.

```yaml
---
- name: Create Folder on Windows Desktop Using WinRM
  hosts: winrm
  gather_facts: no
  vars: 
    folder_name: Anisble_Test

  tasks:
    - name: create folder on desktop
      win_file:
        path: "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\{{ folder_name }}"
        state: directory
      register: result

    - name: Print Result
      debug:
        vars: result
```

This is my host configuration in the default ansible host file. I have intentionally removed the password...

```ini
[winrm]
192.168.10.42 ansible_connection=winrm ansible_winrm_authentication=basic ansible_winrm_transport=http ansible_winrm_port=5985 ansible_user=Admin ansible_password=
```

This is the listener config for http on the windows machine. I have also created the appropriate firewall rule:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> winrm enumerate winrm/config/Listener
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 169.254.93.238, 192.168.10.42, 192.168.80.42, ::1, fe80::e977:b53a:55ce:71ef%17
```

I have also tested the connection from the linux host that I have ansible on and it returned OK:

```
ansible@ansible:/etc/ansible$ nc -z -w1 192.168.10.42 5985;echo $?
0
```

I also have pywinrm installed on the linux machine that ansible is running on:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pywinrm in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (0.3.0)
```

I am now running in circles on troubleshooting and would appreciate any input for this issue.

Comment: As per the link https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/os_guide/windows_winrm.html the ansible vars should be declared under `[winrm:vars]`. Please try and share the outcome

Comment: It's just like the error message says, winrm does not work over http with `authentication=basic`, there's a [whole section about it in the README](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm#encryption)